# Internet Explorer 11 Developer Tools missing resize option

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Where in the Internet Explorer 11 Developer Tools is the "resize" option?,

In IE 10 it was under the Tools menu ...

*Resize - Provides a submenu with a list of predefined screen sizes, and a custom size option.*

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh968260#toolsMenu) ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft removed this feature in the IE11 developer tools. The resolution option provided is, as you point out, not a 100% acceptable substitute since it does not alter the browser window's dimensions.

I haven't yet found a plugin to do the resizing, but seems like ie11 should get one that is like Firefox's Resizer plugin.

In the meantime you could do the resizing via javascript and then hit the content you want to test in the smaller screen size. For example, this website will resize your window for you, just click on your desired resolution: http://resizemybrowser.com/

Comment: Many thanks for that information ... saves me going mad trying to find a non-existent feature

Answer (score 18):

Press F12, It is in emulation tab:

[image]

It is what microsoft recommends to use for different screen sizes:

**Update 1:**

***Display**

*Display emulation helps developers preview their webpages on different screen sizes and different resolutions. It helps identify issues as webpages transition from conventional desktop monitors to smaller mobile screens or newer high-resolution displays.**

Please find more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, this changes resolution. The IE 10 resized the browser window.

Comment: @SteveC I think this is the option available to test different screens. I checked microsoft documentation and they only refer to it in this way.